# Formula vs sentence in the first order logic.

Tags: first-order-logic

There is a little difference between formula and sentence in the first order logic. Sentence is just a formula without a free variables. I consider where there is a **important** difference between them.
I cannot see any one, for example:

$$ \forall x f(x) = 3 \\ \exists x f(x) = 3 \\ f(x) = 3$$
Only the last one is formula but, without a valuation function it is pointless.

Comment: Just $f(x)=3$ by itself is pointless, but if you shorten that statement to $\psi(x)$, you can use it as a building block in larger sentences. Doing that without formulas can quickly become unwieldy. Also, some axioms, definitions and theorems are formulated in terms of formulas, and they need to have room for free variables in that setting.

Comment: Maybe it is pointless... but how you express the semantical specification for $M \vDash \forall x (f(x)=3)$ ? saying that : for every valuation $s$ : $M \vDash (f(x)=3)[s]$.